# how to change proxy in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I was wondering if anyone can help. I goofed up an earlier install of Composer and used proxy settings. I have since uninstalled and tried to re-install. However, the proxy settings from my earlier attempt are visible and the proxy selection box is checked and greyed out. This is messing things up for me as I do NOT want proxy settings. 
Can anyone help me to get rid of those previous proxy settings so I can create new projects in Laravel?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your first installation of Composer added a variable named **http_proxy** to your environment. The value of **http_proxy** is what you see in that input.

All you need to do is delete that variable from the environment and start the re-installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the 'regedit', I deleted it from H_KEY USERS -> ENVIRONMENT, then I reinstalled Composer skipping the proxy setting.